# How to describe cases included in analyses in R?

Tags: r, regression, missing-data

I'm very new to R and pretty basic with analyses generally. I successfully ran a regression in R, but a lot of my data are missing. I'm fine with that because R just ignores the missing observations in the analyses and shows me the dfs in the summary. My problems is that I'd like to look more into the observations that are included in the analyses, but I'm not sure how to do that.

I tried to do na.omit, but R created a dataset with far fewer observations than it used in the regressions, so I think that takes it too far.

Basically, I'm trying to get the ages for the respondents that were included in the final analyses, not just the ages of the entire sample, many of whom were not included in the analyses.

Any advice you can give me would be very appreciated!! Please let me know if you need more information.

Thank you!

Edited to include [Screenshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naiQS.png).

Comment: Hi u/Hmori.  Can you provide an example dataset and the code you were using?  `dput(df)` (where `df` is your data.frame) will allow you to paste output that can be used in your question.  If it is an especially large dataset, you can at least post a portion so that we can see the layout of your data and best be able to help you.

Comment: `?complete.cases` should help identify which cases were used in the regression, and you can use the logical output to index your ages.  `complete_idx <- complete.cases(my_dataframe) `, and `dput(head(my_dataframe, n = 20))` .

Comment: Hi @Chris—thanks for your response! I tried using '?complete.cases' for the regression model, but I got an error message: 'not all arguments have the same length.' I tried using '?complete.cases' on the entire data frame, but it's too large (n = 7,061). Meanwhile, only 1,447 cases ended up in the analysis.

Comment: Hi @chemdork123. Thanks for your response! My dataset is really large (n = 7,061) but with many missing values, most of those cases are eventually eliminated. I tried `dput(df)` and it mostly shows NA.

Comment: @chemdork123 I couldn't figure out how to provide an example of the dataset (I tried `dput`, as well as the `reprex` and `wrapr` packages), so I added a screenshot of the data in my original post. I hope that provides some insight!

Comment: so, something like `dput(head(complete.cases(your_data_frame), n = 20))`, might get your data here. Or then again, maybe not.